# delay mouseUp from firing right after jQuery Ui draggable ends

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

The mouse up event is messing with a drag event I have as soon as the dragging is done, mouse up is fired.

How can I set a delay so that don't allow mouse up to fire until let's say 500ms after drag is done.

I'm using jQuery Ui `.draggable()` so I have access to `stop:`. Would this work:

```
$(element).draggable({
    stop: function(event){
        return false;
    }
});
```

Or is there a more proper way to do it?

**Edit: above code doesn't work. Neither does event.preventDefault();**

Comment: do you need to delay mouseup() event ?

Comment: @SajadLfc yes, I do need to. How can I do it?

Comment: can you add your mouseUp handler for a little more context?